# How To Map Folder Path For Writing In Php - Uploading

Tags: php, file, xampp, fwrite

I'm having trouble with uploading an image to my local server. I test it in `POSTMAN`.

I doubt it is my `$path` that causes the error.

[image: pm]

My `upload.php`

```
header('Content-type : bitmap; charset=utf-8');

if(isset($_POST["encoded_string"])){

    $encoded_string = $_POST["encoded_string"];
    $image_name = $_POST["image_name"];

    $decoded_string = base64_decode($encoded_string);

    $path = 'C:/Users/Luffy/Documents/XAMPP/htdocs/images/'.$image_name;

    $file = fopen($path, 'wb');

    $is_written = fwrite($file, $decoded_string);
    fclose($file);

    if($is_written > 0) {

        $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password','photos');
        $query = "INSERT INTO photos(name,pathFile) values('$image_name','$path');";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) ;

        if($result){
            echo "success";
        }else{
            echo "failed";
        }

        mysqli_close($connection);
    }
}
```

**How do I exactly map folders in Xammp?** I tried getting `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` but it doesn't working.

Comment: You don't have an error yet. You just have code that doesn't do what you expected it to do. If `$result` is `false` then you need to check `mysqli_error($connection)` to get the actual error returned from your dbms and start there.

Comment: I'm adding `mysqli_error($connection)` at the end of the statement of $result.

Comment: It gives me this -  `fopen(images/hehe.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C: \...\....\. `

Comment: Read this Anwser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory have you permission to the folder =?

Comment: I didn't create a dir programmatically, I created a sample folder for placing images intentionally. Does it need file permission - to write? Thanks for the link I'm looking to it also.

Comment: It's working now, but `POSTMAN` will give me this error - `Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'` - but my icon is uploaded in the folder - images. Can I ask a question? Is this how I locate `path` / `map` my folder ? I assume that since I'm inside `XAMMP` - it will look for it's directory inside `htdocs` .